# Java packaging naming convention and domains with "-" character

Tags: java, naming-conventions, package

I know that the best practice to name java packages is to use a domain name backwards.

But suppose my domain is in the form www.word1-word2.com. When I try to create a package in eclipse or Android Studio named com.word1-word2.Myapp, I receive an error message (the - character can not be used).

An alternative is to use com.word1_word2.MyApp... but the bad new is that these domain is registered to another person.

Wich alternatives do you recomend me?

Thnks.

Comment: Uhhh.. I don't understand.. Are you asking for URL recommendations or are you asking alternatives to your package name..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that other company also offering Java packages? If not, you shouldn't care that much, since your issue would be that a client would use your package plus the competitor package, and that both packages contain a class with the exact same name.

C and Objective-C developers build libraries for clients without wondering that much of package name uniqueness, since there are no package names.

If you want, just add a little something to the package name, like com.world1word2.productname.